# Play Framework post Image file to server and store it under resources

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, playframework

I'm sending an image from client side to my server which is implemented with Java in the Play Framework

```
$scope.uploadPicture = function() {
    var image = $("#titlePicture img").attr("src");

    $.ajax({
        url: "api/uploadPicture",
        type: "POST",
        data: image,
        async: false,
        success: function (msg) {
            // ...
        },
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false
    });
}
```

In the request-header of my POST request I have the following Content-Type:

```
    text/plain; charset=UTF-8
```

The POST itself contains, as seen above, the data from the image:

```
data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQ[...]
```

The routing works fine. I do receive the below mentioned message in the success part of my ajax request:

```
public Result uploadPicture() {
    // Store the image data under local folder ressources
    return ok("File uploaded");
}
```

My question is on how I implement the commented line.

Comment: If you want to save `Base64` string you can plainly write to some file, else you would need to convert it to equivalent image and save it than.

Comment: Within my controller I receive an empty body:
Http.RequestBody body = request().body();

I don't know how to retrieve the send data.

Comment: Now I'm confused: What is your question? How to retrieve the send data? Or: How to store it within Play's resources? With the latter question I'd agree with @Darshan Lila, you could just write it to a file like with any other file too.